# Unity/C# - Compiler Errors ONLY in VSCode, not Unity Editor or Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

When trying to reference a class from a Unity package (specifically `InputSystem`), VSCode will give me the errors `The type or namespace name 'InputSystem' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [Assembly-CSharp]`, even though Unity builds and runs just fine with no complaints, and generating the project files for Visual Studio work properly.

This started when trying to move to VSCode from Visual Studio as my main editor, so something in that process likely broke them. I have tried a bunch of different things - deleting and regenerating the `.csproj` and `.sln` files, uninstalling, reinstalling, and updating the package, even deleting the whole repo and re-cloning but nothing has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is definetely a unity/ide integration problem. Try following [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity) official guide to setup VSC Unity support.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow [this tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity) instructions for using vs code with unity? Because some things need to be installed in order for you to use vs code with unity.

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not have enough creds, I am writing this as an answer.

How did you move from Visual Studio to VS Code ? I hope you changed it in Edit > Preferences >External Tools> External Script Editor.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to regenerate the Project Files from Unity?

```
Edit > Preferences > External Tools > Regenerate Project Files
```

This usually works fixing corrupted (or not compatible) *.csproj files.